# Show $\{x_n\}$ converges if $\left| x_{n+1}-x_n \right| \lt \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers and $\left| x_{n+1}-x_n \right| \lt \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

My strategy is to show the sequence is Cauchy and since it's a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, it is convergent.

Proof:

Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and w.l.o.g. let $n \gt m$, then

$\left| x_n - x_m \right|$

$= \left| x_n - x_{n-1} + x_{n-1} - x_{n-2} + x_{n-2} + ...+ x_{m+1} - x_m \right|$

$\leq \left| x_n - x_{n-1} \right| + ... + \left| x_{m+1} - x_m \right|$

$\lt \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{n-1} + \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{n-2} + ... + \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^m = \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^m \left[ \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{n-m-1} + ... + 1 \right]$  ......$(\dagger)$

Using the geometric formula $\left[ \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{n-m-1} + ... + 1 \right] = 4 \left( 1 - \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^{n-m-1} \right) \lt 4$

So $\dagger$ becomes,

$\left| x_n - x_m \right| \lt 4 \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^m$

Now we want $4 \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^m \lt \epsilon$

or $\left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^m \lt \frac{\epsilon}{4}$

Can I simply say, choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $m \geq N$ the above is true?

Can I get some verification of my approach as well as some help with what to do in the last step?

Comment: Whether you can simply say such stuff depends on the context, of course. But if I needed to show that with only basic math, I would have gone by
$$
\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^m < \frac{3}{4}\frac{4}{5}\cdots\frac{m+2}{m+3} = \frac{3}{m+3}.
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning the last step, all you need is to take $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\left(\frac34\right)^N<\frac\varepsilon4$. Then, if $n>m\geqslant N$,$$\lvert x_m-x_n\rvert<\left(\frac34\right)^m\leqslant\left(\frac34\right)^N<\frac\varepsilon4.$$The rest of what you did looks fine.

Comment: If it was something simple like $\frac{1}{N} \lt 4\epsilon$ then I can argue by Archimedes property, I can find $N$ large enough so that the inequality holds. But in this case, is there something "concrete" like the Archimedes property that I can cite?

Comment: Note that $\left(\frac34\right)^N<\frac\varepsilon4\iff\left(\frac43\right)^N>\frac4\varepsilon$. And now you can use Bernoulli's inequality:$$\left(\frac43\right)^N=\left(1+\frac13\right)^N\geqslant1+\frac N3.$$And $1+\frac N3>\frac4\varepsilon$ if N is large enough by the Archimedian propert.